# how to send my game made with pygame to others?

Tags: python, pygame, publish, send

I'm new to making games with pygame and my first attempt is still a work in progress, but I was wondering how to publish or send my game to my friends who don't have pygame so that they can play it. I looked online but haven't found anything useful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can package your project into a standalone distributable application that has its own python environment.

OSX: py2app
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2app/

Linux: pyinstaller
http://www.pyinstaller.org/

Win: py2exe
http://www.py2exe.org/

Note, you can use pyinstaller cross platform. I just have had good personal experience with this mix.

Comment: Note: pygame depends on an external library (or .dll on windows). [This](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/Pygame2exe) is good if you use py2exe.